# Error in Jquery Ajax request, it always executes the error block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending an ajax call to my server, where parameter is "general" or any text, for a search query, why is it always giving error. The response is in `JSON`, and I have already mentioned it, any issues with the code below? Any help will be highly appreciated

```
$.ajax({
    url : "${kb_endpoint_url}",
    dataType : 'json',
    data : { search_query : queryValue }, // queryValue = general
    success : function(data) {
            console.log("success");
    },

     error: function ( xhr, status, error) {
      console.log( " xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText + " //status: " + status + " //Error: "+error );

    }
```

**This prints:** `xhr.responseText: undefined //status: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character //Error: undefined`

**Edit**: I tried changing the type to application/json and now the console prints

xhr.responseText: undefined //status: No conversion from text to application/json //Error: undefined

Comment: According to error, your response is not in json or your json file is broken.

Comment: @AmitJoki - Yes, it is stored in a freemarker variable

Answer (score 0):

```
xhr.responseText: undefined //status: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character //Error: undefined
```

I think ; this error means that the response coming back from your URL is not JSON, there's an error attempting to parse it as such.

Either look in your network panel (easier), or adjust your error handler to see what response your server is actually returning, by looking at the [responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Analyzing_and_manipulating_HTML_responseText)

Comment: strange part is that responseText is returning the correct reponse

Answer (score 0):

If the server is returning the text `undefined`, this is not valid JSON and cannot be parsed.
Only `null` is valid in JSON format, so trying to parse `undefined` will give this error.

For examples:

```
JSON.parse("undefined"); // Throws an error, "Unexpected token u"
JSON.parse("null");      // Returns null
```

Answer (score -1):

If you comment `dataType : 'json',` your `ajax` runs properly. Your response  is not in `JSON` format.

```
    $.ajax({
        url : "${kb_endpoint_url}",
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'post',
        data : { search_query : queryValue }, // queryValue = general
        success : function(data) {
                console.log("success");
        },

         error: function ( xhr, status, error) {
          console.log( " xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText + " //status: " + status + " //Error: "+error );

        }
});
```

Another file (mentioned url )

```
<?php

echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```